# What does $\mathbb{Z}_2$ mean?

Tags: number-theory, notation, terminology

Wich number space is ment by:  $\mathbb{Z}_2$

(I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ stands for Integer)

Comment: The integers mod 2.

Comment: The classes of even and odd integers

Comment: Or 2-adic integers. It all depends on the context.

Comment: The other usual suspect is the ring of $2$-adic integers.

Comment: ok, in my case it should be mod 2.

Comment: Does any of those voting to close (because the question is "missing other context or details") care to give a short explanation on *why*? What context is needed?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_n$, read "the integers mod $n$", essentially partitions the integers into $n$ "residue classes".  The [division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem) provides a natural framework for assigning an arbitrary integer $x$ to a particular residue class.  That is, by dividing that integer $x$ by $n$, we can rewrite $x$ as $an + r$ for some unique $a, r \in \mathbb{Z}$.  While $a$ is known as the *quotient* of this division, we are really interested in the *remainder*, $r$.

When the division algorithm is carried out, the remainder $r$ lies strictly in the range $0 \leq r<n$, and hence there are $n$ possible values for $r$.  These are the residue classes.  So for example, $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0, 1\}$, since any number, when divided by $2$, will yield a remainder of either $0$ or $1$.  This is intuitive because any given integer is either even or odd.

For a concrete example, let's take a look at $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.  By the above, we are partitioning the integers into $10$ residue classes.  So to which does the integer $47$ belong?  Well, the division algorithm tells us that $47 = 4 \cdot 10 + 7$, where $4$ is the quotient and $7$ the remainder.  Hence, $47$ corresponds to the residue class "$7$" in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.  Typically, this is written as $47 \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$.